# why does my Pc not able to power on

Tags: windows-7, display, cpu

Am using windows 7 CPU till last week its working fine ,last week change the pc location to other from that time display wont come, but when  power on CPU its getting on  and also i checked the processor Ram its all fine But i cant able to see the display in monitor don't know what's the problem

PC is Acer Aspire
Intel core 2 duo processor
4gb Ram
500 GB HD
Gigabyte Motherboard

Comment: You said you have moved your PC to another location. Open it up and make sure your GPU is still correctly placed in the motherboard - if not, this could cause your problem.

Comment: Check the power supply.  Also check to see if the RAM is properly seated in its socket.

Answer (score 0):

could be lots of things
1.bad power supply
2.bad battery
3. bad switch
4. Loose connection

If you can access another power supply: try it. If not and you have a volt meter: see if the power supply is supplying power. If the power supply is good: remove the battery and see if that makes a difference